# Append code to a block from included partial

Tags: twig

I have a `js` block in my template that collects all javascripts on the bottom of the page. I usually extend base template and append JSs using `parent()` Twig function to keep child scripts below parent ones. It works well but now I would like to include a partial that would also append scripts to the `js` block. Something like this:
http://twigfiddle.com/3w8g0o

I want following order:

```
main content 1  
partial content
main content 2
base js
main js
partial js
```

If I use `use` instead of `include`, then `parent()` returns `js` block from `partial.twig` instead of `base.twig`.

The only solution I found would be to

1. Add `use` of the partial above the main content block
2. Replace `include` with `block('partial_content')`
3. Append `js` from `main.twig` with `block('partial_js')`

http://twigfiddle.com/3w8g0o/2

which means there are 3 things to remember when including new partial instead of 1 which will probably lead to forgetting something some day. Is there an easier (one line from `main.twig` preferably, `partial.twig` can be more complex) way to achieve my desired order?

Comment: If you are trying to append to a block from inside an include, then this is not possible atm.

Comment: Oh, okay, I see. Thanks.